# php date plus 1 year outputting weird date

Tags: php

I want to add one year to `$joindate` for the value of `$exdate`.

The php code is as shown below:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$joindate = date("d/m/Y");
$exdate = date("d/m/Y",
    strtotime(date("d/m/Y", strtotime($joindate)) . " + 365 day"));
```

However, when I echo out both variables I get this:

> Join date : 16/12/2011
>   Ex Date : 01/01/1971

(the ex date should be 16/12/2012)

Anyone knows where is the mistake I made?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$exdate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("+ 365 day"));`

And the `$exdate` will be `15/12/2012` because 2012 is leap year which has 366 days.

Comment: the output of this is 15/12/2012 instead of 16/12/2012(that i want). Is this some kind of bug php have? thanks for replying.

Comment: It can be years with 366 days)

Answer (score 8):

```
$joindate = date('d/m/Y');
$exdate   = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+1 year'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 $date = strtotime("+365 day", strtotime("2011-12-16"));
 echo date("Y-m-d", $date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at mktime() in the PHP manual ([here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php))

With it you can add days, months, years, hours, minutes and seconds to an existing date like this:

```
$date = "2011-12-16";
$dateTime = strtotime($date);

$day = date("d", $dateTime);
$month = date("m", $dateTime);
$year = date("Y", $dateTime) + 1;
$hour = date("H", $dateTime);
$minute = date("i", $dateTime);
$second = date("s", $dateTime);

$nextYearTime = mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);  

$nextDate = date("Y-m-d", $nextYearTime);
```

You can also wrap this code (or variations on it) into a function for portability.

Answer (score 1):

the most easiest way of adding a year to current year is this intval(date('Y'))+1.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can also work if you change format to "m/d/Y"

Answer (score 0):

try this line of code.

```
$dateOneYearAdded = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($currentDate)) . " +1 year");
echo "Date After one year: ".date('l dS \o\f F Y', $dateOneYearAdded)."<br>";
```

Thanks.